# 2 Dimensional List View

Tags: java, android

I've got a question regarding list views in Android. I want to create an activity that can display lots of information. I want to display each player horizontally (there could be anywhere from 2 to 256 players, but most likely there will be like 8) and there will be 10 - 20 rows under each player.

Is there a way to create a `ListView` that can scroll both directions? If not, what is the correct design approach to handle this type of problem?

I've tried to look into this a bit, and a `GridView` won't work because there will be items hanging off the screen; they won't all fit in the grid.

Thanks!
-Justin

Comment: Sounds like you want an `ExpandableListView`

Comment: Thanks all for the good places to look. I decided that [this devbyte](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tRg_eDfQ8fk) is as close to what I need as I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ViewPager instead so that the user can scroll through the player in the horizontal way that you want.

This way each player will be in a fragment, and the fragment can contain a vertical list that will show the rows that you require.

The benefit of this is that the viewpager can handle a huge number of players and rows for each player without impacting memory performance and in a less cramped space.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using an ExpandableListView or a ViewPager.